# Showing a sql table when radio button is selected using AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a webpage with three radio buttons and an empty table. My goal is to select a radio button and have the table show a list of employees based on whichever radio button is clicked. Right now the list does not show up when I hit the button. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried adding an alert to the doAjax function and the alert appeared so I know it's getting to that function. Below is my code, I have three files. Any help is appreciated.

```
//assign3.php
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
          <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
    <script src ="js/assign3js.js" type = "text/javascript" ></script>

</head>
<body>

    <table border ='1'style = 'margin:auto' id = "employees" >
        <tr><td colspan ='3'><h1>Employees </h1></td></tr>
        <th> First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
    </table>
        <input type="radio" name="employeeType" value="server" id="server"> Server<br>
        <input type="radio" name="employeeType" value="bartender"id="bartender"> Bartender<br>
        <input type="radio" name="employeeType" value="host"id = "hosts"> Host<br>

</body>
```

//script.js

```
$("document").ready(
function()
{
$("#server").click(doAjax);
$("#hosts").click(doAjax1);
$("#bartender").click(doAjax2);  
}
);

function doAjax()
{
$.ajax({"method":"POST","url":"servers.php"}).done(update);
}
function update(data)
{
result = JSON.parse(data);
for(index =0; index < result.length; index++)
{
    var row = "<tr>";
    row += "<td>" + result[index].firstName + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + result[index].lastName + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + result[index].employeeID + "</td>";
    row += "</tr>";
    $("#employees").append(row);       
 }
}
```

//server.php

```
    <?php

 $server = (object) null;
 $connection = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=restaurant";
 $user = "root";
 $pwd = "mysql";
 $db = new PDO($connection, $user, $pwd);
 $results = $db->query("SELECT firstName, lastName, employeeID  FROM 
 employee JOIN `server` ON employee.employeeID = server.employeeID");
 while ($row = $results->fetch()) 
 {   
 $server->firstName= $row["firstName"]; 
 $server-> lastName=$row["lastName"] ;
 $server->employeeId = $row["employeeID"];  
 }
 $employee = [];
 array_push($employee,$server);

$json1 = json_encode($employee);
echo $json1;
?>
```

Comment: Q1: Is it assign3js.js = script.js? Q2: Which name has the page with the html code? Is it "server.php" too? Q3: Why "?" in the form's action?

Comment: Q2: assign3.php has the html.  Q3: I'm not sure why the ? that's just the way my teacher has taught it. But I'm not doing anything with that specific block of code right now so I removed it from the question.

Comment: Put this code as the first two lines in your server.php, in order to be able to see eventual php errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`followed by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: Any php errors displayed?

Comment: I did not see any php errors displayed when I added that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is wrong, you have it doing

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, employeeID FROM employee JOIN `server` ON 
employee.employeeID = server.employeeID
```

but employeeID exists in both employee and server so you need to modify your query to specific which table to get employeeID from so it should look like

```
SELECT employee.firstName, employee.lastName, employee.employeeID FROM employee JOIN `server` ON 
employee.employeeID = server.employeeID
```

I made an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cefbd3/2/0) which shows this. You should check if $results equals false, because the query function will return false if it fails.
That worked for me, I had to change line 14 in server.php as well or else it wouldn't display the employee ID, this was because in the ajax script you reference it as employeeID but you set it as employeeId on line 14 so it would now be

```
$server->employeeID = $row["employeeID"];
```

Now when you run all of it will only one employee, if you want it to return multiple you need to have an array in server.php that you push employees to because right now it will overwrite the previous employee and only return the last one because of them writing to the same object with the same keys.
For multiple employees to return I changed the code to

```
...
$server = [];
...
$count = 0;
while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    //create new class to stop warnings of creating object from empty value
    $server[$count] = new \stdClass();
    $server[$count]->firstName= $row["firstName"];
    $server[$count]->lastName=$row["lastName"] ;
    $server[$count]->employeeID = $row["employeeID"];
    $count++;
}
...
```

what this does is $server is now an array, and every time we loop over an employee in the while loop we assign our values to a new object stored in $server's array.
and the script.js looked like this

```
function update(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data)[0]; // [0] because the json was wrapped in 
    // double []'s
    for(var index =0; index < result.length; index++) {
        var row = "<tr>";
        row += "<td>" + result[index].firstName + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + result[index].lastName + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + result[index].employeeID + "</td>";
        row += "</tr>";
        $("#employees").append(row);
    }
}
```

Not sure if any of this is the best solution to the problem, but I got it to work without too much trouble.

Comment: Alex, `data` is an array with multiple objects in it (the employee objects). `JSON.parse(data)[0]` will parse only the first object. I might be wrong, though; I can't test it.

Comment: I tested it and the only way for it to work is to have the [0] there, atleast for me. The JSON was [[{some data}]] and without the [0] it wouldn't work.
I'm not that familiar with JSON but my understanding is that I need the [0] there to select the first object because the array I'm selecting is in an array

Comment: Then you are right! To me it was `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`, but I was in the middle of testing another code variant.

Comment: Thank you for your response, what you wrote makes sense and I made the changes. When I press the radio button nothing appears in my table. There must be something wrong with my ajax, I have been working on this for hours and can't seem to get past this part.

Comment: Can you add something like console.log(data); at the start of the update function and tell us what it says in the console when you click the ajax button? It should print out the data that the ajax request is returning.

Comment: I added that and then inspected the webpage on chrome  and have two error appear                                                                           assign3js.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at assign3js.js:42
3assign3.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.update (assign3js.js:44)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: Okay so the reference error is because you are trying to log the variable data which doesn't exist, in the code you provided inside the function method of assign3js.js it does so you must of put the console.log at a different location or the variable going into the function is not called data, if it is called something else rename it inside the console.log so we can see what ajax request returns. The JSON parse error is probably because the php script server.php is throwing an error which is being returned with the data(if the data is even being returned)

Comment: I fixed that and put it inside the function and the data error is gone. Now all I have is the JSON Parse error.   VM670:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Okay so if you add the lines aendeerei mentioned `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the server.php file after the `<?php` but before anything else then click the radio button, does it still only say the json parse error or does it print the data to the console? Your JSON should be fine if you followed my answer so I'm not sure how to tell what is wrong without knowing what the JSON that can't parse is.

Comment: Ooops I fixed it now I don't have an error but get this in the console [{"firstName":"ken","lastName":"kirby","employeeID":"3"},{"firstName":"lynn","lastName":"lewis","employeeID":"4"}]]    just does not go into my table

Comment: Then you have to use the jquery's [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function in your `update()` function in js, instead of the vanilla javascript's `for` statement.

Comment: Alex, great job! ;-) I like your answer and the detailed comments. Good luck.

Comment: Is it still not going into the table? If it adds the first to the table but not the second like your data does for me I believe it has to do with the actual data.
Thanks aendeerei, great work on your answer it looks very well done.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is just an addition to @alex's answer. Alex has very good pointed out the main problems/aspects!

I would suggest you another approach: to use only one js function for getting the employee data, no matter which radio button you are selecting. When you click on a radio button, send an ajax request with the corresponding radio button's value as argument. This value will be read on the server side and, dependent on it, a corresponding sql statement will be built and executed. The response will be read and appended to the employees table.

There would be too much to say here regarding your code version and my proposal. I hope you'll understand what I did.

Main points:

- I renamed "server.php" to "get-employee.php" (it's obvious why).
- I implemented the use of prepared statements instead of `query`, so that you are on a safe side in regard of the sql injection, in case you need to use input parameters in your queries.
- The employee data is fetched from db and saved in an array by using the `fetchAll()` method. No need for fetching and looping through objects.
- The db connection details are defined in constants.
- An array with db connection options regarding exception handling and others is added now (needed).
- Added the `tbody` container to the table, to which the employees data will be appended. In general, if you use `th` then use it inside a `thead` container. And if you use `thead`, then use a `tbody` too.

I think this is all that's important. Feel free to ask me anything... tomorrow.

Good luck further.

#### assign3js.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="employeeType"]').click(function () {
        var employeeType = $(this).val();
        updateEmployees(employeeType);
    });
});

function updateEmployees(type) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'get-employee.php',
        data: {
            'type': type
        }
    })
    .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var row = '<tr>';
                row += '<td>' + response[i].firstName + '</td>';
                row += '<td>' + response[i].lastName + '</td>';
                row += '<td>' + response[i].employeeID + '</td>';
                row += '</tr>';
                $('#employees tbody').append(row);
            }
        } else {
            $('#employees tbody').append('<tr><td colspan="3">No employees found</td></tr>');
        }

    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // alert(textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    })
    .always(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //...
    });
}
```

#### assign3.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/assign3js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #employees {
                /*margin: auto;*/
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            #employee-types {
                margin-top: 20px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table id="employees">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">
                        <h1>Employees</h1>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

        <fieldset id="employee-types">
            <legend>Employee type</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="server" name="employeeType" value="server">
            <label for="server">Server</label><br/>

            <input type="radio" id="bartender" name="employeeType" value="bartender">
            <label for="bartender">Bartender</label><br/>

            <input type="radio" id="hosts" name="employeeType" value="host">
            <label for="hosts">Host</label><br/>
        </fieldset>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### get-employee.php

```
<?php

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'restaurant');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'mysql');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

// Error reporting.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER!
//
// Create a PDO instance as db connection to db.
$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);

$response = false;

if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $employeeType = $_POST['type'];

    /*
     * The bindings array, mapping the named markers from the sql statement 
     * (if any) to the corresponding values. It will be directly passed as 
     * argument to the PDOStatement::execute method.
     * 
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
     */
    $bindings = [];

    // Set the sql statement based on the submitted employee type.
    switch ($employeeType) {
        case 'bartender':
            // $sql = '...';
            // $bindings[:markerName] = markerValue;
            break;
        case 'hosts':
            // $sql = '...';
            // $bindings[:markerName] = markerValue;
            break;
        case 'server':
        default:
            $sql = 'SELECT 
                        emp.firstName,
                        emp.lastName,
                        emp.employeeID 
                    FROM employee AS emp
                    JOIN `server` AS srv ON srv.employeeID = emp.employeeID';
            break;
    }

    // Prepare the sql statement for execution and return a statement object.
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

    // Execute the prepared statement.
    $statement->execute($bindings);

    // Fetch data - all at once - and save it into response array.
    $response = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ...or fetch data one record at a time and save it into response array.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // $employee = [];
    // while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //     $employee[] = $row;
    // }
    // $response = $employee;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
}

echo json_encode($response);
```